# How to segment users in Google Analytics by the number of pageviews they produce?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to know how many users on my website are making one pageview only, how many do two pageviews and how many do three and so on.

I am using Google Analytics as a tracking tool and would like to get a solution using that tool.

I am open for any suggestion from segmention to using the API to creating custom dimensions and so on.

Cheers
Christian

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google Analytics usage and is not programing related.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear what you are asking - if you want to know how to create a dynamic segment for an API call this might be on-topic (but to walk you through the API would make this too broad, and possibly not necessary for your use case), but if you merely want to know how to create segments in the user interface then you might rather ask webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pageDepth dimension: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagedepth